# SQL Filestream - tying up rows with File Stream files

Tags: sql-server, filestream

hopefully a simple question to settle my intrigue more than anything. I have setup Filestream on our SQL Server. From what I have read I was expecting to see the GUID in the database row match the filestream file name in the file path... but they dont match. Is there any other wizardry going on that I am missing?

**Database Table**:
[image]
where column id is the GUID and FileData is the Filestream column.

When I then go to the location where these BLOBS are being stored, I expect to see these GUIDs as the filenames:

**Filestream Files**
[image]

I am just looking to understand the whole process of how Filestream works. I have done a bit of digging around so if anyone is able to fill in those gaps for me would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing. But below is what I eventually figured out.

[image: File Stream Table - Hidden under "File Tables" folder]

> Notice the column circled in red above. The type and name may be different.

```
DECLARE @BaseDirectory AS varchar(200) = '\\server-name\Instance\DocumentPages\';
SELECT TOP(10) @BaseDirectory + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(200), file_stream.PathName(0)), LEN('file_stream\') + CHARINDEX('file_stream\', CONVERT(varchar(200), file_stream.PathName(0)), 1), 36) + '.' + dp.file_type, d.DocumentID
FROM [Document].[dbo].[DocumentPages] AS dp
    INNER JOIN [Document].[dbo].[Documents] AS d
        ON d.stream_id = dp.stream_id
ORDER BY d.DocumentID DESC
```

This query uses a function called .PathName() on this column. This isn't how I have known SQL to typically work (usually, functions take the column value in as a parameter). But it does!

> Because our system is using Availability Groups, I had to find the base directory and ignore what SQL Server was returning.

You may also try file_stream.PathName(0), file_stream.PathName(1), or file_stream.PathName(2) to try and find the base path. And if the path matches, remove the SUBSTRING logic!

Hopefully Helpful!